# pylint attribute-defined-outside-init; but attributes are in __init__() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, init, pylint

I am creating a class to connect to a neo4j database. The `__init__()` method sets the necessary attributes, authenticates and checks the connection.
When I run **pylint** it gives the `attribute-defined-outside-init` error on `password`, `user` and `graph_url`; although I think I did put them in correct. Python seems to be happy with it.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
from py2neo import authenticate, Graph

class NeoConnector(object):
    """Creates a NeoConnector object that can connect to a Neo4j graph
    database and perform operations like upload nodes and relationships,
    drop the database, index labels and properties."""

    def __init__(self, url, user, password, database):
        """Setup the graph, authenticate and connect"""
        self.graph_url = url
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

        authenticate(url, user, password)
        graph = Graph(''.join(["http://", url, database]))
        try:
            graph.neo4j_version
        except:
            print """\nDisconnected from Neo4j.
            Please check if the cord is unplugged."""
            print graph
            print ''
        else:
            print '\nConnected to Neo4j; version:', graph.neo4j_version
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I could only find other questions that concern setting attributes outside of the **init**() method on purpose.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in pylint other than some unimportant ones

Comment: Do you still get the warning now that you're spelling `__init__` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although correct, this still did not do the trick. I ended up reinstalling pylint and now the error is not showing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't

```
def __init_
```

be spelled

```
def __init__
```

?

Comment: I couldn't post a comment with less than 50 rep. Besides, the author edited  it's code. We are not yet given informations  about wether or not this modification solved his issue.

Comment: Although correct, this still did not do the trick. I ended up reinstalling pylint and now the error is not showing anymore.